# QEvent ownership

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I want to send both predefined and custom `QEvent` to a Qt application.
Is the event required be allocated on the heap or can I just pass the pointer to a object on the stack?

```
QKeyEvent stackevent(QEvent::KeyPress);
QKeyEvent* heapevent = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress);

QEvent * event;
event = &stackevent; //valid ??
event = heapevent;
QCoreApplication()->notify(someobj, event);
delete heapevent; //valid? or lost ownership?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> event = &stackevent; //valid ??

Usually that's not safe, but in this case it's valid, because the function [`notify`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#notify) won't return, untill the event is handled (or not) by someone (it means that `stackevent` will be "alive" during this operation).

> delete heapevent; //valid? or lost ownership?

Yap, that's valid too, because normally nobody should hold a pointer to the QEvent (and delete it, of course) and btw it has already been processed.

The situation **significantly** changes when [`postEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) is used:

> The event must be **allocated on the heap** since the post event queue will take ownership of the event and delete it once it has been posted. It is not safe to access the event after it has been posted.

Well, I guess it's more suitable to use stack allocation in your situation and passing a pointer to it in case of any possible problems (memory automatically will be released).

Comment: thanks for the clear answer. welcome to SO. Looking forward to read your future answers.